# In Azure Data Factory, how do I pass the Index of a ForEach as a parameter properly

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Sorry if this is a bit vague or rambly, I'm still getting to grips with Data Factory and a lot of it seems a bit obtuse...

What I want to do is query my Cosmos Database for a list of Ids of records that need to be updated. For each of these records, I want to call a REST API using the Id (i.e. /Record/{Id}/Details)

I've created a Data Flow that took a string as a parameter and then called the REST API fine.

I then made a pipeline using a Lookup with a query (select c.RecordId from c where...) and pass that into a ForEach with items set to @activity('Lookup1').output.value

I then setup the Activity of the ForEach to my Data flow. From research, I think I'm supposed to set the Parameter value to "@item().RecordId", but that gives an error "parameter [name] does not match parameter type 'string'".

I can change the type of the parameter to any (and use toString([parameter]) to cast it ) and then when I try and debug it passes the parameter in, but it gives an error of "Job failed due to reason: at (Line 2/Col 14): Datatype any not found".

I'm not sure what the solution is. Is there a way to cast the result of the lookup to an integer or string? Is there a way to narrow an any down? Is there a better way than toString() that would work? Is there a better way than ForEach?

Comment: Please can you add images what's you are trying?

Comment: Have you tried "@string(item().RecordId)” ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce similar scenario what you are trying.

- **My sample data in cosmos**
  [image]

To query Cosmos Database for a list of Ids and call a REST API using the Id For each of these records.

First, I took Lookup activity in data factory and selected the `id's` where the `last_name` is `Bluth`

**Its output and settings are as below:**
[image]

Then I passed the output of lookup activity to For-each activity.
[image]

Then inside for each activity I created Dataflow activity and for that DataSource I gave the source as Rest API. My Rest API to call specific user is `https://reqres.in/api/users/2` I gave base URL as `https://reqres.in/api/users`.
[image]

Then I created parameter called `demoId` as datatype `string` and in relative URL I gave that dynamic value as `@dataset().demoId`
[image]
[image]

After this I gave value source parameter as `@item().id` as after `https://reqres.in/api/users` there is only id should be provided to get data in you case you can try **`Record/@{item().id}/Details`**.
[image]

**For each id it is successfully passing id to rest API and fetching data:**
[image]

Comment: So the issue I think here is that in your example the Ids are stored in Cosmos as strings (with the double quotes around them), but I'm storing them as integers (no quotes).

This carries through, as my preview data is { "id": 1}{ "id": 2} etc., whilst yours is { "id": "1"} { "id": "2"}

Thus, if I try to pass them in as a string parameter within the foreach, they are the wrong type and it doesn't seem to work...

I guess a solution would be to store the id as a string in cosmos DB, but that doesn't feel a particularly elegant solution...

Comment: you can convert int value string by using `@string(item().id)` in source 1 parameter.